# Which items in Chimera Squad are one time use?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

I'm looking for an explanation of which items in XCOM: Chimera Squad can be reused and which are consumed after one mission. Googling hasn't really turned up anything useful, so I'd be very grateful for an explanation.

In particular, are Breaching Charges and Auto Key Cards consumed? What about grenades or tranq rounds?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no perishable items in the game. Some items have limited amounts of uses in the field (eg: Breaching Charge only works once per mission), but they are not deleted after using them in the field, you can reuse them next mission.

Furthermore, tranquilizer rounds (and other types of ammunition) aren't limited at all, you can reload as many times as you want in a mission and you'll still have their effect. Naturally, they'll also remain after the mission is over.

Answer (score 7):

There are no consumable items in XCOM:Chimera Squad (or if there are, I did not encounter any). Items and abilities can be limited to:

- Once per x turns (cooldown)
- Once per encounter
- Once per mission

Any equippable items will be available again after the mission is over. So there is no reason to not make use of them, especially during the last encounter of a mission. And there is no reason to buy more than one of each either, unless you intend to bring more than one of them on the same mission (usually you don't, because there are just so many different items available)

Grenades are usually once-per-mission, but the agent Claymore can learn the optional ability "Improvised Explosives" on his 2nd promotion which upgrades grenades in his inventory to once-per-encounter.

Breach-items like breaching charges and key cards are all once-per-mission. But it is pretty rare to encounter the same kind of item-accessible breach point more than once in a single mission. Further, you often don't need to bring a key card, because those agents who are accompanied by a Gremlin drone (Terminal and Patchwork) do not need a key-card to access keycard-accessible breach points. So you usually should carry one breaching charge at most and use the breach item slots of all other agents for items which provide a bonus during the breach.

Special ammunitions are not limited at all. They apply to all shots fired by that agent while equipped.

Comment: Ammunition does not affect Blueblood's Lancer pistol, IIRC.

Comment: I don't think I ran into any once-per-encounter stuff. It was either turnlocked, or once per mission. Can you think of any examples?